# Azure Event Hub Schema Registry for JSON Serialization always auto generates schema

Tags: json, azure-eventhub, azure-eventhub-client

The *auto.register.schemas* option for a JSON schema registry group in event hub does not seem to work.

Using sample json producer project for [azure-schema-registry-for-kafka](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka), I expect a validation error (or some type of error) if I set [auto.register.schemas property to false](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka/blob/master/java/json/samples/producer/src/main/java/com/azure/schemaregistry/samples/producer/KafkaJsonSpecificRecord.java#L34) and change the schema of the data I'm sending.  Instead it will create a new version of my schema with my updates.

I can reproduce this in the [Schema Registry JSON Producer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka/tree/master/java/json/samples/producer) sample project referenced in Azure Event Hub documentation sample project example by changing the CustomerInvoice class.

I have verified this setting works in the Avro Schema Registry.  Both tests were done with the kafka client.